# How to change an inequality when we raise it to the power of n?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

I'm sorry if this is a beginner question but let's say for example:

$x>-1$: is $x^2>1$, or $x^2<1$, or $x^2>0$? what is the correct answer?

and let's say $6>x>-3$, how to find $x^2$? because it's not $36>x^2>9$.

is there a general rule?

THANKS

Comment: For the second part, you can break it into two parts, solve each independently and then merge back together. For the first part, I recommend you give some more try, perhaps plugging in some values to see the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to separate the cases $x\ge 0$ and $x<0$:
If $x>-1$, then either $-1<x<0$, which implies $\:0<x^2<1$, or $x\ge 0$, for which $x^2\ge 0$. So the answer in terms of intervals, is
$$(0,1)\cup[0,+\infty)=[0,+\infty).$$

The second example yields this: if $-3 <x<6$, we have either $x\in (-3,0)$, whence $x^2\in(0,9)$, or  $x\in [0,6)$, whence $x^2\in[0,36)$, and the final result is the last interval.

Comment: thanks a lot that makes sense

Comment: The main point is to never forget  $x^2is increasing on positive numbers and decreasing on the negative.

Answer (score 0):

The axiom we are allowed to use is if $a < b$ (and it doesn't matter if $a,b$ are positive negative, one is zero, one is neg and the other positive) and **if we have that $c > 0$** (that is an *absolutely* required condition) then we have that $ac < bc$.

ANd from that we can conclude that if $0 < a < b$ then because $a > 0$ then $a< b \implies a*a < b*a$, and because $b > 0$ then $a < b \implies a*b < b*b$.  So we can conclude that $a^2 < a*b < b*b = b^2$.

But that *ABSOLUTELY* requires that $b$ is positive and $a$ is non-negative. It will *not* work if $a < 0$.

Now we can by induction assume if $0 < a < b$ than $a^2 < b^2$ and that means $a^3=a^2*a < a^2*b < b^2*b = b^3$ and so on if $a^k < b^k$ then $a^{k+1} =a^k*a < a^k*b < b^k*b = b^{k+1}$. So if $0 < a < b$ we *can* conclude $a^n < b^n$

but if $a < 0$ we *cant* do that.  In fact we *must* do the exact opposite.

If $a < b$ and $c < 0$, then $c + (-c) < 0 + (-c)$ and $0 < -c$.  So $a*(-c) < b*(-c)$ and $-ac < -bc$.  So $-ac + ac < -bc + ac$ so $0 < -bc +ac=ac -bc$ so $0 + bc < ac -bc+bc$ and $bc < ac$.

So if $a < b$ and $c < 0$ then $bc < ac$.

ANd if $a < b < 0$ then $a^2 = a*a > a*b$.  And $a < b$ so $a*b > b*b = b^2$ and we have $a^2 > b^2$.

And so you *flip* the inequality.

Now if we have $x > -1$ we are a bit stuck as we don't know if $x$ is positive of negative of zero.

I $-1 < x < 0$ then $x$ is negative so $x > -1$ means $x^2 < 1$ and we have $0 < x^2 < 1$.

ANd if $-1 < 0 = x$ then the $-1$ has nothing to do with anything and we have $x^2 = 0$.

And if $-1 < 0 < x$ then the $-1$ has nothing to do with anything. an you have $x^2 >0$

The only real thing we can conclude is that $x^2 \ge 0$ but that no surprise.  Squares are *never* negative.

To do $6 > x > -3$ we must do three cases.

1. If $6 > x > 0$ then $36 > x^2>0$.
2. If $x=0$ then $x^2 = 0$.
3. if $0 > x > -3$ then $0 < x^2 < 9$.

One ***OR*** the other of the three cases are true.

Putting them togeter we have .  Can conclude $0 \le x^2 < 36$.  We can further say, $x^2 = 0$ only if $x = 0$ and that if $x< 0$ we further know that $x$ is negative the $x^2 < 9$>